# How to apply Text cell format permanently on a google sheet's column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, data-validation, power-query

I recently added IDs as Number in a column those are basically built as alphanumeric.

Then I've applied Text cell format on those IDs to keep their data consistent with the other cells in that column, but it keeps reverting back to a Number when I refresh the table and rejecting the VLOOKUP I've applied.

How can I keep every cell permanently as General data format or store it as Text on every refresh I do?

Here's an example of what the data column looks like:

| Serial Number | Data Type (not part of the table but to show the dtypes) |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Stored as text / General |
| **999999** | **Number** |
| B08WXYZ | Stored as text / General |
| 789DCA1234 | Stored as text / General |
| GUT1234LESS | Stored as text / General |

Image of example of what it [looks like and what I'm trying to avoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJc7.png)

Comment: Your question title refers to **Google Sheets**.  Yet your question seems to have more to do with **Excel** and **Power query**, and you do not use the Google Sheets tag.  How are you getting the output of your query into google sheets?  If this were Excel, all you have to do is properly define your type in PQ.  But you seem to be doing something with Sheets, and it is not clear what that is.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the table"? Are you using and add-on, Apps Script or something else to do it?

Comment: Since you need something the automation [then better check this](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-macros/)